# Keras set output of intermediate layer to 0 or 1 based on threshold

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a model that has "classification" and "regression" like parts. I merge them using multiplication layer. Before performing multiplication I want to set outputs of classification part to 0 or 1 based on threshold. I tried to use Lambda layer with custom function as below, however I am facing various errors, and I have no clue about those errors. Resolving them one by one as I go does not add to my understanding. Can anyone explain how to define custom Lambda layer function that modifies the values?

**My current Lambda layer function:** (not working due to `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value lstm_32/bias`)

```
def func(x):    
    a = x.eval(session=tf.Session())
    a[x < 0.5] = 0
    a[x >= 0.5] = 1
    return K.variable(a)
```

**Regression part:**

```
input1 = Input(shape=(1, ))
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size + 1, embedding, input_length=1))
model.add(LSTM(hidden, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(6))
model.add(Reshape((3,2)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
```

**Classification part:**

```
input2 = Input(shape=(1, ))
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Embedding(vocab_size + 1, embedding, input_length=1))
model2.add(LSTM(hidden, recurrent_dropout=0.1, return_sequences=True))
model2.add(LSTM(1))
model2.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model2.add(???)  # need to add 0-1 thresholding here
```

**Merge two parts:**

```
reg_head = model(input1)
clf_head = model2(input2)    
merge_head = multiply(inputs=[clf_head, reg_head])
m2 = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=merge_head)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `func`, you cannot `eval` the tensors.

The idea of using tensors is that they keep a "connection" (a graph, as they call it) from start to end in the entire model. This connection allows the model to compute gradients. If you eval a tensor and try to use these values, you will break the connection.

Also, for taking the actual values of a tensor, you need the input data. And the input data will only exist when you call `fit`, `predict`, and similar methods. In the build phase there isn't data, only representations and connections.

A possible function using only tensors is:

```
def func(x):

    greater = K.greater_equal(x, 0.5) #will return boolean values
    greater = K.cast(greater, dtype=K.floatx()) #will convert bool to 0 and 1    
    return greater
```

But be careful! This will not be differentiable. These values will be seen as constants from now on in the model. This means that the weights coming before this point will not be updated during training (you won't train the classification model via `m2`, but you will still be able to train it from `model2`). There are some fancy workarounds for this, if you need them, please write a comment.

Use this function in a `Lambda` layer:

```
model.add(Lambda(func, output_shape=yourOutputShapeIfUsingTheano))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question regarding the last paragraph. Should I run model2.fit(X, y) before running m2.fit(X2, y2) in order to optimize the classifier?

Comment: I am also getting the following error: ValueError: Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported. I tried other conversion routines, and still facing the ValueError.

Comment: Hmm, you must use a `Lambda` layer with the function, see update in the answer.

Comment: If you still get the none type error, it's probably because the function is non differentiable. This might be solved with `model2.trainable=False` before compiling the full model. (If you do need model2 to be trainable, let me know).

Comment: Yes, ideally I would like to have model2 trainable.